# Looking to use filter in swift to filter inner array of structs while not touching outer array

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, filter

Here is a playground I created to attempt to create the correct filter:
What I want to return is all of the outside structs and any inside array values which meet a "text" block which will be inbound from a search bar.

```
//: Playground - noun: a place where people can play

import UIKit
import Foundation

struct events{
    var title:String
    var unique:Int
    var swimmers_info:[swim_info]

}

struct swim_info{
    var name:String
    var team:String
}

var arrayEV:[events]
var si1:[swim_info]
var si2:[swim_info]

si1 = [
    swim_info(name:"Smith, John",team:"PHNX"),
        swim_info(name:"Tenay, Teresa",team:"CRIM")
]

si2 = [
    swim_info(name:"Test, Two",team:"PHNX"),
    swim_info(name:"Female, Swimmer",team:"SSA")
]


arrayEV = [
    events(title: "First Event",unique: 5,swimmers_info:si1),
    events(title: "Second Event",unique: 2,swimmers_info:si2)
]

//print(arrayEV)

var newarrayEV1 = arrayEV.filter({(value) -> Bool in
    return value.swimmers_info.contains(where: {$0.team == "SSA"})
})

var newarrayEV2 = arrayEV.map({$0.swimmers_info.filter({(value) -> Bool in
    return value.team == "SSA"
})})


print(newarrayEV1)
```

YEILDS [__lldb_expr_42.events(title: "Second Event", unique: 2, swimmers_info: [__lldb_expr_42.swim_info(name: "Test, Two", team: "PHNX"), __lldb_expr_42.swim_info(name: "Female, Swimmer", team: "SSA")])]

**Incorect becuase it yeilds only the second main struct an both sub structs

```
print("  ")
print(newarrayEV2   )
```

[[], [__lldb_expr_42.swim_info(name: "Female, Swimmer", team: "SSA")]]

**Incorrect because drops all main struct information**

```
print("11")
```

**KINDA CORRECT**

I can get the desired result with:

```
for (index,loop) in arrayEV.enumerated(){
    //print(String(describing: index))
    //print(loop.swimmers_info)
    var new_si = loop.swimmers_info.filter({(value) -> Bool in
        return value.team == "SSA"
    })
    //print(new_si)
    arrayEV[index].swimmers_info = new_si

}
```

however I'm not sure if this is the best way to attack this.

Comment: `var arrayEV:[events]` could you also add the `events` struct?

Comment: It is Swift naming convention to name your structures starting with an uppercase letter and CamelCase instead of Snake_case

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on your suggested "solution", I think this is what you're after:

```
arrayEV = arrayEV.map {
    var ev = $0
    ev.swimmers_info = ev.swimmers_info.filter {$0.team == "SSA"}
    return ev
}
```

The reason for the rather clumsy-looking three-liner is that we cannot mutate a struct's property unless the reference to the struct itself is a `var` reference — but `map` provides us with a `let` reference (`$0`).

Comment: Thanks I think that htis might work. I will write it into a filarrayEV to filter it because I never touch the actual initial array from the JSON/REST call

Comment: Unable to infer complex closure return type; add explicit type to disambiguate is the error I'm gettin on the above.

Comment: Update your version of Swift then. It works fine for me.

Comment: My Bad since I was using another variable to store the filtered stuff I had to take that into account and declare the type of the new varaiable.

Comment: yeah both work...so I'm not sure if I can accept both

Answer (score 1):

Create a method in your `event` class which check the text with inner array and with his own `title` and tells you that this class fall in `match-case` or not

```
struct events{
    var title:String
    var unique:Int
    var swimmers_info:[swim_info]

    func haveSameText(_ text: String) -> Bool {
        let filtersArray = swimmers_info.filter { (info) -> Bool in
            return info.name.lowercased() == text.lowercased()
        }
        return filtersArray.count >= 0 || text.lowercased() == title.lowercased()
    }
}

struct swim_info{
    var name:String
    var team:String
}
```

To filter event array on the base of some text use below method.

```
var eventArr = [events]()
var filteredArray = eventArr.filter { (event) -> Bool in
    return event.haveSameText("text")
}
```

Comment: I'm not quite understanding the          return filtersArray.count >= 0 || text.lowercased() == title.lowercased()

Comment: you want to filter event on the base of their swiming info name or their event title right?

Comment: Two scenarios are acceptable:  UISearchController. Start typing in name.."Smith, John" is the swimmer. As I type in S..m..i then only the 1 event with the 1 swimmer should show in the table. Scenario 2 would be that all events(section headers(outer struct)) show but all are empty expect for the one that contains "Smith, John" which wold return 1 row for that section

Comment: added to the original post... I found a long winded answer but not sure if this si the best way to attack it